# Binomial distribution vs. Discrete uniform distribution. vs. randomly selecting

Tags: normal-distribution, data-visualization, binomial-distribution, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

I have an array of $n$ non-negative integers where each element can be randomly (uniformly) selected with repetitions from all the integers between 0 and $m$ (with $m>n$). So the probability of each element having a particular value is $1/m$.

(Example: an array of 10 elements randomly selected between 0 and 255) - picked 255 because that is the maximum value of a 1 byte variable.

Now, from my understanding of the Binomial distribution, the previous scenario can be described with the Binomial distribution of $N=10$ and $p=1/256$, which will make a binomial distribution graph (heavily) skewed to the left.

[[image: Binomial distribution of <span class=]$N=10$ and $p=1/256$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftprc.png)

But now, if I consider all the elements in bits, here is my question. Each element can be described in bit-size. So this problem would be equivalent to select $N=10*8=80$ elements from $\left\{0,1\right\}$ with probability $1/2$, and the Binomial distribution would be centered in $40$ and would look like the normal distribution.

[[image: Binomial distribution for <span class=]$N=80$ and $p=1/2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma19J.png)

My questions are

1. Why the graphs are different if they are representing the same action?
2. How do I interpret the difference in these two graphs?
3. Are both graphs describing then an event of selecting elements (uniformly) randomly?

Thank you.

Comment: If one picks 10 times an integer uniformly over $\{0,1,\ldots,256\}$, one does not produce a Binomial outcome.

Comment: Why not? If you have a vector of 10 elements $[x_1,\dots,x_{10}]$ you can decompose this event into 10 independent Bernoulli experiments $Y_1,\dots,Y_{10}$ where success of $Y_i$ is picking $x_i$ (i.e., probability = 1/256).

Comment: Each of the $x_i$'s can take among 256 values. These random variables are not Bernoulli, as opposed to $\mathbb I_j(x_i)$ say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not represent the same action. The binomial distribution with parameters n and p gives you the number of successes in n independent trials, each with a probability of success p. If I understood your examples correctly, in your first example, there are 10 trials each with p=1/256; let random variable X~Bin(n=10,p=1/256); X will take on only 11 values {0,1,...,10}, corresponding to the events {0 successes in 10 trials, ... , 10 successes in 10 trials}. In your second example, there are 80 trials each with p=0.5; let random variable Y~Bin(n=80,p=0.5); Y will take on a total of 81 values {0,1,...,80}, corresponding to the events {0 successes in 80 trials, ... , 80 successes in 80 trials}. X and Y are very different random variables with very different PMFs.

Comment: Example 1 is equivalent to check the probability of having exactly 10 matches in 10 trials with a match having probability of $1/256$ (which is $\binom{10}{10}*(1/256)^{10}(1-1/256)^0=(1/256)^{10}$). Example 2 is equivalent to check the probability of having exactly 80 matches in 80 trials with a match having prob. $1/2$ which is $\binom{80}{80}(1/2)^{80}(1/2)^0=(1/2)^{80}=(1/256)^{10}$. So they have the same PMF, no?

Comment: Your second comment/question underscores your misunderstanding. The answer is no. The binomial distribution and uniform distribution are very different.